# Target Current Instance of class using Jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox, target

I have this almost figured out. Can someone help me?

I can't seem to figure out how to only target the current checkbox and text and not every instance in the code. Basically what I'm trying to do is, if a checkbox is clicked, change the value of the text along with adding a class to it.

HTML:

```
<div class="dependents">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <h5>You <span>(covered)</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>(born Feb 2, 1976)</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Edit Details</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <h5><input type="checkbox" name="dependents"> Jane <span>(not covered)</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Spouse <span>(born Oct 20, 1973)</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Edit Details</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <h5><input type="checkbox" name="dependents"> Mark <span>(not covered)</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Spouse <span>(born Nov 11, 2003)</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Edit Details</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <h5><input type="checkbox" name="dependents"> Susan <span>(not covered)</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Spouse <span>(born Sep 22, 2000)</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Edit Details</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.dependents {}
.dependents > ul { }
.dependents > ul > li { padding: 22px 11px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #c5c6c7; list-style: none; display: block;}
.dependents > ul > li > div { float:left; width: 33.33%;}
.dependents > ul > li > div:last-child { float:right; text-align: right;}
.dependents > ul > li > div > h5 > span { color: #ff0000;}
.dependents > ul > li > div > h5 > span.covered { color: #090;}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.dependents > ul > li > div > h5 > input').click(function(){
    var $depCov = $('.dependents > ul > li > div > h5 > span');

    $depCov.toggleClass('covered');
    if ($depCov.html() == "(covered)")
        $depCov.html('(not covered)');
    else
        $depCov.html('(covered)');
});
```

I've posted a demo on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YbhKy/7/

Any other suggestions would gladly accepted.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var $depCov = $('.dependents > ul > li > div > h5 > span');
```

Into:

```
var $depCov = $(this).parent().find('span');
```

or

```
var $depCov = $(this).next('span');
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YbhKy/8/).

The reason yours didn't work is because you selected all of them. Look into the [DOM Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
var $depCov = $(this).next('span');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YbhKy/9/)